# Expanding horizontal nested list below a main list with jQuery slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list `(.mainMenu)` with a nested list `(.subMenu)` that I want to dropdown on click. Basically I want the nested list to slide toggle down to reveal it on click but I'm having trouble as i need the nested list to sit below the main list.

I wondered if there is anyway of achieving this without applying `position: absolute;` to the `.subMenu`. The reason `position:absolute` is not suitable for me is I need everything below `.mainMenu` to be pushed up/down when the menu is opened/closed.

Heres my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ezsP/129/) of what I have so far. Heres a [website](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/symmetry/styles/beatnik/preview) that has what I'm trying to achieve (click Men in main menu to see function).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Main +
    <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
        <li>Sub</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>

<div class-"main-content">
    All content below the menu that needs to move up down as and when subMenu is opened/closed.
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.mainMenu').children('li').on('click', function() {
   $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

Hopefully I'm being clear if anyone knows of any tutorials or can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it I'm finding it hard to find any help online.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

Comment: If you want the submenu to show beneath the main menu, you should structure your html accordingly. Right now it is inside your main menu and thus moves its parent's siblings. The alternative to restructure your html is to force the menu out of DOM continuity by positioning.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response I thought the structure might have been wrong but I couldn't get my header round how to achieve it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your level of CSS and as sugested on the comments it would be easier for you to use any library with the widget you need, as jQueryUI or maybe Bootstrap.

Anyway, if you want to follow just as you were doing here you have an updated fiddler to achieve what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ezsP/130/

This is the code:

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
   <li>Link</li>
   <li id="option1">Main +</li>
   <li>Link</li>
   <li>Link</li>
   <li>Link</li>
   <li>Link</li>
</ul>
<ul id="subMenu1">
   <li>Sub</li>
   <li>Sub</li>
   <li>Sub</li>
   <li>Sub</li>
</ul>

<div class-"main-content">
   All content below the menu that needs to move up down as and when subMenu is opened/closed.
</div>



ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#subMenu1 {
    display: none;
}



$('#option1').on('click', function() {
       $('#subMenu1').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I thought maybe it had to come out of being nested but I couldn't get my head around how I would achieve it. I guess I was thinking about it all wrong. I'm pretty sure this is what I need. I'll try implementing this into my site and let you know how I get on. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Just one side note: Try using more ids on your html/css. It will make your life easier... The selector is direct and you don't have to add classes, look for children, etc. Don't hesitate to ask something more. And please, check the answer as accepted, don't just vote it up... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you solve it like the example page you showed? Instead of placing the submenu inside the mainmenu just place the submenu as an isolated element below the mainmenu.

You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MarkusToe/d1evmn0o/) how I tried to solve it.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
    <li>Link</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="subLink">Main +</a></li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
</ul>

<ul class="subMenu">
    <li>Sub</li>
    <li>Sub</li>
    <li>Sub</li>
    <li>Sub</li>
</ul>

<div class-"main-content">All content below the menu that needs to move up down as and when subMenu is opened/closed.</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".subLink").click(function(){
    $(this).text() === "Main +" ? $(this).text("Main -") : $(this).text("Main +");
    $(".subMenu").slideToggle("slow");
});
```